# rsync - copy files created newer than x days

Tags: rsync

I am trying to copy files newer than 7 days old only using rsync between 2 servers on the same network. Using the below

```
rsync -RDa0P \
        --files-from=<(find /mnt/user/data/ -type f -mtime -1  -print0) \
        . pi@10.10.20.196:/srv/dev-disk-by-label-nvme/data/
```

However i get the following error

```
rsync: link_stat "/root/mnt/user/data/sunset.jpg" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I dont understand why it is putting /root before the path.

However if i run the below only

```
find /mnt/user/Media/Movies/ -type f -mtime -1  -print0
```

I dont get the /root added to the path i get the below as expected.

```
/mnt/user/data/sunset.jpg
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were running the command in the `/root` directory. The path is prepended to the filenames since you used `.` as source.

Change `.` to `/` and it should work with the absolute file paths returned by `find`.